# How To Order A Hierarchical Table By Two Parameters In MySQL?

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I have a table with some hierarchical data in it. I've handled ordering it in a hierarchical way via calculating the path with a trigger but now I wanna sort them with another parameter too.
Take a look at these pictures:

This Is The Table With Hierarchical Data Ordered By Path:

[image]

I Expect These Two Rows To Swap Because Row `ID = 4` Has A Date Before Row `ID = 2`:

[image]

So How Can I Order Each Level By Date Column?

**NOTE:**
The ID Is A Random Number Generated By A TRIGGER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`FIND_IN_SET`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) so as to extract the hierarchy level of each row. Then use this in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT ID, Name, ParentId, Date, Path
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, REPLACE(Path, '.', ',')), Date
```

Note: We have to use `REPLACE` function to replace `'.'` characters with `','`
so that `FIND_IN_SET` works as expected.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45b12/4)

Alternatively you can modify your trigger so as to generate an additional 'level' field and use this field in the `ORDER BY` clause of your query.

Comment: Life Saving Solution. Can You Explain The `FIND_IN_SET` Part? How Did This Solved The Problem?

Comment: thanks this is a good solution. so one more question. what is the effect of the index of first occurence of ID in Path?

Comment: To understand it better include `FIND_IN_SET(ID, REPLACE(Path, '.', ','))` in the `SELECT` clause of your query just to see the number it returns for every row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the date in the path-column on each level, since you cannot simply order by date.

So the path-column should look something like this:

0.date-2015-12-09 22:15:12.parent1.date-2015-12-09 22:15:14.parent4

0.date-2015-12-09 22:15:12.parent1.date-2015-12-09 22:15:17.parent2

In that case, date superceeds the parent-level.
In this situation 1.4 would appear before 1.2, because 1.4 happend before 1.2

The path-column does get a little lengthy, but its the only way you can incorporate your own hierachy, I think

Did I get it this time? :-)
Hope I could help :-)

Comment: not that easy buddy. I said each level. this only works if two rows have same paths

Comment: ahh ok wait.. I was to fast, let me look into that

Comment: really tricky solution. sound like a working one too. let me test it